# Is it possible to use templates to identify two different types?

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I've got the following code. I have to define the `operator()` for all types available in `MyVariant` (bool, int, string, const char*). However, since `StartsWith` is only applicable to type string, all other functors should return false.

```
#include "boost/variant/variant.hpp"
#include "boost/variant/apply_visitor.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

typedef variant<bool, int, string, const char*> MyVariant;

class StartsWith
    : public boost::static_visitor<bool>
{
public:
    string mPrefix;
    bool operator()(string &other) const
    {
        return other.compare(0, mPrefix.length(), mPrefix);
    }
    bool operator()(int &other) const
    {
        return false;
    }
    bool operator()(bool &other) const
    {
        return false;
    }
    bool operator()(const char* other) const
    {
        return false;
    }
    StartsWith(string const& prefix):mPrefix(prefix){}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    MyVariant s1 = "hello world!";
    if(apply_visitor(StartsWith("hel"), s1))
    {
        cout << "starts with" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works fine. But in order to make it more concise, I thought it might be possible to use templates to have one functor for string, and one for other types. I tried the following, but the result is that the second functor is always the one invoked.

```
template<typename T>
class StartsWith
    : public boost::static_visitor<bool>
{
public:
    T mPrefix;
    bool operator()(T &other) const
    {
        return other.compare(0, mPrefix.length(), mPrefix);
    }
    template<typename U>
    bool operator()(U &other)const
    {
        return false;
    }
    StartsWith(T const& prefix):mPrefix(prefix){}
};
```

The following code did not work either:

```
class StartsWith
    : public boost::static_visitor<bool>
{
public:
    string mPrefix;
    bool operator()(string &other) const
    {
        return other.compare(0, mPrefix.length(), mPrefix);
    }
    template<typename U>
    bool operator()(U &other)const
    {
        return false;
    }
    StartsWith(string const& prefix):mPrefix(prefix){}
};
```

Is there anyway I can avoid multiple "return false" statements for types other than string?

Comment: "hel" type is `const char*`, not `string`.

Comment: `template<typename U> bool operator()(U &other)const` works for me. It's probably because you're using `const char*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `const char*` in my variant. Changing the following line:

```
MyVariant s1 = "hello world!";
```

to

```
MyVariant s1 = string("hello world!");
```

solved the problem and got the template version working.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool operator()(std::string const& other ) const {...}
template< class T >
typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_same<T, std::string>, bool >::type
operator()( T const& ) const {return false;}
```

Comment: It doesn't work: "/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:832:32: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be"

Comment: You are right it is unnecessary for your case, but I want to show how you can enable or disable functions based on the type and avoid multiple functions with same syntax, but as you say this is overdoing for your case

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me:

```
class StartsWith
    : public boost::static_visitor<bool>
{
public:
    string mPrefix;
    bool operator()(const string &other) const
    {
        return other.compare(0, mPrefix.length(), mPrefix);
    }
    template<typename U>
    bool operator()(U other)const
    {
        return false;
    }
    StartsWith(string const& prefix):mPrefix(prefix){}
};
```

Off topic: [std::string::compare()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) returns `int`.

Comment: Could you please create a copy of the code that you tested and worked in [http://ideone.com](http://ideone.com/)?